# In C#- Retrieving data from selected item in combo box and fill into data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I want to retrieve data from combo box and fill it into data grid view. I am using Visual Studio C# Windows Form. My application is using MySql database in retrieving data for column price, user, and date. I tried this code but It doesn't fill anything in data grid view. I have no problem filling my database at first but after I added the combo box to be filled in data grid view it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public void loadDataGridView_Main()
{
    dgvMain.Rows.Clear();
    List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect(comboProd.SelectedItem + "Select * From sales");
    for (int i = 0; i < detailList.Length; i++)
    {
        dgvMain.Rows.Add(detailList[i][0], detailList[i][1], detailList[i][2], detailList[i][3]);
    }
}
```

Automatically Load in Form.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = new MyLibrary("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
    loadDataGridView_Main();
    dataLog();
    fillCombo();
}
```

**comboProd is the variable name for my** `comboBox`

Here's my `fillCombo` method I have no problem with this

```
public void fillCombo()
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                             "DATABASE=cashieringdb;" +
                                 "UID=root;" +
                              "PASSWORD='';";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    string command = "select productAdd from settings";
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    comboProd.DataSource = dt;
    comboProd.DisplayMember = "productAdd";
    connection.Close();
}
```

This function is only for adding products and to be retrieved in `ComboBox`, for example if I add Apple product it will save into database and the `ComboBox` will retrieve the product apple to be added on the list.

**EDIT**

so here's the flow of my program.

in my data grid view I have 1 `ComboBox` and 3 columns to be field in my data `GridView`. in the `ComboBox` it will fill my selected item in database side it will retrieve the value anything that is in the database. That is the reason I coded it this way.

```
List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect(comboProd.SelectedItem + "Select *
```

BUT I am not sure in this line. I am sceptical. I think the wrong is somewhere here.

Comment: Can we see the fillCombo method? Are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Also, you're using comboProd.SelectedItem, but you call for loadDataGridMainView_Main before populating the combo box using fillCombo(). This could mean that the combo box doesn't have a selected value yet,

Comment: @Shane.C I honestly don't know what I am doing at that line of code can you please give me more details about that line?

Comment: Try calling your methods in a different order. if you're basing the datagrid off of a selected item on the combo box, you want to populate that first. So try calling fillCombo() before loadDataGridView_Main(), that way there will be items in the combo box that you're using in your datagrid filling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = new MyLibrary("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
    fillCombo();   //fill combo before calling loadDataGridView_Main()
    loadDataGridView_Main();
    dataLog();    
}
```

Just replaced one statement. Now check it.

Comment: Thank you for that it also help but still I can't see anything in data grid view.

Comment: Please notice this line comboProd.SelectedItem + "Select * From sales" I am not so sure about this.

Comment: Why are you adding `comboProd.SelectedItem` with a straight forward query?? and how many columns does your `sales` table have?

Comment: my sales table have 3 columns

Comment: the array is ok. Forget the database thing what I want to achieve is to fill the data grid view with my selected item in combo box and second is to fill it from database table sales.

Comment: I figure out the problem I set the column to 6 instead of 4 LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn class. Set DataSource and assign ValueMember and DisplayMember columns as required. Add the obj to datagridview

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dgc.DataSource = ds;
dgc.ValueMember = "columnname1";
dgc.DisplayMember = "columnname2"

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc);
```